# Does the usage of the word 'absenteeism' in relation to COVID match with the standard usage of the word?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absenteeism)  defines 'absenteeism' as staying away **without good reason** which to me immediately implies some kind of judgement of the reasons for staying away. However I've seen the word used in relation to the COVID pandemic, for example [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/52908/are-supermarket-shelves-in-australia-currently-empty-because-of-absenteeism-due) (note that both Australia's Chief Medical Officer Paul Kelly as well as the question asker use the word) where it is used when businesses struggle because too many employees do not come to work due to COVID.

To me the word 'absenteeism' here implies that Paul Kelly wants to say that COVID is not a good reason to stay away from work. Is this the intended meaning here or can the word also be used in a neutral way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/absenteeism) [adjusted] first lists the default stipulative meaning of the word:

> **absenteeism** [noun] [non-count]:   a situation in which people are not at school or work when they should be

but then goes on (in the 'Cambridge Business English Dictionary' reference) to allow the logical, caveat-lacking definition as well as the default sense:

> **absenteeism** [noun] [non-count]: the fact of staying away from work, especially without a good reason

However, using a non-default sense (here, the broader sense) without pointing out that one is doing so (or without at least obviously forcing context) is violating the Gricean maxim of clarity. I'd certainly use 'absence from work due to Covid' here.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absenteeism) defines it as "chronic absence (as from work or school)" with no mention of whether it's justified.

Comment: AHD and RHK Webster's similarly have no caveat. Yet Lexico, and Wikipedia include the 'without good reason' requirement as necessary and Collins and Macmillan have 'usually without a good reason'. Yes, Stuart, different dictionaries, doubtless all employing competent researchers carrying out sensible surveys, come up with different results which they faithfully base their decisions on.  The word is ill-defined, and using such a word without pointing out the intended sense (or without at least obviously forcing context to do so) is violating the Gricean maxim of clarity.